# Passport-ldapauth fails to execute verify callback

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js

Please , I have setup passport ldapauth which works fine with all parameters, the problem is if the username or password is wrong, the it does not execute further to the verify callback function at all. It just stops. Due to this I cannot give feedback to the users to indicate what is actually wrong. Is there any clue what I am missing?. This is the structure

```
passport.use('ldapStudent', new LdapStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passReqToCallback:true,
        server: {
            url: '..........',
            bindDn: '.............',
            bindCredentials: '..........',
            searchBase: '..............',
            searchFilter: '.............',
            searchAttributes: ['givenName','sn'],
            tlsOptions: {
                ca: [fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt', 'utf8')]
            }
        }
    },
    function (req, user, done) {
        //now check from the DB if user exist

        if(user){

            //check if user email exist;
            User.findOne({'EmailAddress': user}, function (err, userdata) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                //user exist redirect to home page and send user object to session
                if (userdata) {
                    //userActivity(PostActivity);
                    console.log(userdata);
                    return done(null, userdata);
                }else {
                    //new user, add them to the user model
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.EmailAddress = req.body.username,
                        newUser.JoinedDate = Date.now(),
                        newUser.UserType = 'Student'
                    newUser.save(function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error in Saving NewUser: ' + err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(result);
                            var PostActivity = {
                                ActivityName: req.res.__('Student Joined'),
                                ActivityDate: Date.now(),
                                UserID: result._id,
                                UserIP: (req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress ) + ' Port: ' + req.connection.remotePort
                            };
                            userActivity(PostActivity);
                            console.log('User Registration successful');
                            return done(null, newUser, req.flash('SuccessMessage', req.res.__('You have been successfully Registered')));
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

        }else{
            return done(null, false, req.flash('ValidationError', req.res.__('Wrong password and/or email address')));

        }}));
```

This is where i actually do the login

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapStudent', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/userlogin',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

The code works well , just as I expect, the parameters for the ldap option object are intentionally omitted. 
The problem is when the user credential are not correct, the verify callback does not get executed at all and so, I can not return a flash message for the user to know what is happening

Answer (score 0):

`passport-ldapauth` does not execute the verify callback if there is nothing to verify which is the case if the credentials are incorrect and the user is not received. This is in general how the strategies tend to work, e.g. `passport-local` does not execute verify callback if the  [username or password is missing](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/6643e87abf3f8edb65e44b668b58bb8b2217ed9d/lib/strategy.js#L74-L76).

Strategies, `passport-ldapauth` included, also usually include a (configurable) message for the failure flash. General configurable login failure messages for `passport-ldapauth` are listed [in the documentation](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/blob/0b7e1d0c4b065e979ad25996417b5ee8a68e7ad4/README.md#authenticate-requests). Each of the messages also has a default value so even when not configured the failure flash message is set (given of course that you have [flash middleware in use](http://passportjs.org/docs#flash-messages))

Also, you are *not* supposed to use `req.flash()` in the callback of the verify function but to [supply an info message](http://passportjs.org/docs#verify-callback).